# Parse json in python when as dict when only one "node"

Tags: python, json, python-requests, python-responses

I am able to parse json ressponse when there are multiple "nodes" of what I am looking for, but when only one node is returned by the API, I am getting the message "string indices must be integers". 
Here is my code in which I am pass in the dictionary after converting it from a string using json.loads():

```
import requests, requests.auth
import json
import os

def parseSchedule(dict):
    i = 0
    for item in dict['reservations']['reservation']:
        print(item['event_start_dt'])
        i += 1
```

I've simplified the json response to show that this works:

```
    {
    "reservations": {
        "reservation": [{
            "event_start_dt": "2019-11-27T12:40:00-08:00"
        }, {
            "event_start_dt": "2019-11-27T16:10:00-08:00"
        }]
    }
}
```

While this throws the error "string indices must be integers":

```
    {
    "reservations": {
        "reservation": {
            "event_start_dt": "2019-11-26T08:30:00-08:00"   
        }
    }
}
```

I have researched the .items() in which I attempt the key and value but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: But in the second case you don't need a loop, just `dict['reservations']['reservation']['event_start_dt']`.

Comment: Actually I do need a loop because I never know how many returns I will get from day to day -- sometimes just one but most likely multiple returns..

Comment: It makes no sense to have a data structure that is sometimes an list and sometimes a dict.

Comment: @ProgrammerBret Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Indeed -- much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```py
#If it is a list:
if str(type(dict["reservations"]["reservation"])) == "<class 'list'>":
    for i in range(len(dict["reservations"]["reservation"])):
        print(dict["reservations"]["reservation"][i]["event_start_dt"])
else: #If it is not a list
    print(dict['reservations']['reservation']['event_start_dt'])
```

Comment: Yes this works --  I ended up using the isinstance method of checking whether it was a list or a dict after researching .. thx very much !!